# Get country domain code

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c

I have an app that I am making a basic built-in web browser for with pre-populated bookmarks.

But I want to get the country domain code of the device for example .com, .uk, .de etc. Is this possible?

I know how to get the country code using `NSLocale` but that gives GB instead of uk.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a `if`.

The country codes are defined in ISO-3166, and match the country code top level domains. The only exception is the United Kingdom, whose ISO-3166 is GB, but it keeps using the .uk domain defined before ISO-3166 was written.

Comment: Yes. A complete list is in http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_Internet_top-level_domains#Country_code_top-level_domains